# Get return value of function and tee output

Tags: bash, zsh

I want to run a few commands and have all the output go **stdout** plus I want to send the last 10K bytes to `hc-ping.com` along with the status.

I've got the output working, but I seem to have lost the status code. I'm not quite sure which command the `$?` refers to -- is it **the previous command in the pipe-line** or **the one at the start**?

Regardless, I want to capture the return or **exit value** from `main()`.

How can I do that?

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env -S bash -fuo pipefail

hc_ping='https://hc-ping.com/xxx'
curl -fsS -m 10 -o /dev/null --retry 5 "$hc_ping/start"

main() {
  echo "do stuff"
  return 5
}

main |& tee /dev/tty | tail --bytes=10000 | curl -fsS -m 10 -o /dev/null --data-binary @- --retry 5 "$hc_ping/$?"
```

N.B. solutions for `zsh` are fine too if bash doesn't have the needed features.

Comment: @jared_mamrot Hmmm...doesn't seem to work. Can you use `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` inside the same pipe chain?

Comment: `$?` in this case is the exit status of `main`'s definition (`main() { ...`), which is 0. And `PIPESTATUS` can't be used here either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can make this work as a one-liner; at the time the shell is
putting together the pipeline and resolving `$?`, `main()` hasn't yet started.
Also, later processes in the pipeline (e.g. `curl`) may be launched before `main` finishes.

Can you split it into two commands?

```
mainout=$(main |& tee /dev/tty | tail --bytes=10000; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
mainret=$?

curl -fsS -m 10 -o /dev/null --data-binary @- --retry 5 \
    "$hc_ping/${mainret}" <<< "${mainout}"
```

Since you're cutting off the output at 10K, you should not reach any
implementation limits with variables in modern shells. Note that the command substitution `$(...)` will trim any trailing newlines.

Comment: I don't think I need `$PIPESTATUS` with `-o pipefail` actually, but this works!

Answer (score 4):

I would do something along the lines of @Gairfowl's answer, but using a named pipe.

```
mkfifo p

# Blocks until anything is written to the named pipe "p".
# Run in the background so we can call main and write to p.
tail --bytes=10000 p |
  curl -fsS -m 10 -o /dev/null --data-binary @- --retry 5 "$hc_ping/$?" &

# Write both to p and standard output
main | tee p

# And get the exit status of main, not tee
echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
```

Comment: Didn't know about `mkfifo` that's pretty cool. I would have really liked this solution, but it has one fatal flaw -- the exit status of main needs to go to `$hc_ping/$?`

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice what `curl` actually used for the URL.